# Base hard disk attached to wrong differencing disk UUID

Tags: virtualbox

I cloned a disk with CloneVDI to increase the size, failed to tell it to use the same UUID, then renamed the old base VDI file and dropped the large clone in its place.  I tried to start it up and VirtualBox complained of a UUID mis-match, so instead I removed the the original and added the new one and tried to start it up.

The cloned disk does not appear to have merged the differencing disk.  When I boot it up it thinks it's 2014 and all of my files since then are absent.

I tried to re-add the original VDI and remove the new one and it created a new differencing disk, so now it's booting up in 2014 too.

The differencing disk VDI from before I began all of this idiocy is still there in the snapshots directory with a different UUID.  How can I tell VirtualBox to use that UUID rather than the new one so that I can boot up to the state as of earlier today?

Barring that, is there a way to manually merge the base disk and the specific differencing disk?

tl;dr: I am an idiot; please save me from myself.